# Can adaptive be added to a non-enhanced weapon?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, magic-items, weapons

As part of loot there was a non-magical masterwork composite (+2) [longbow](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/equipment---final/weapons#martial-ranged).

I am wanting to upgrade the bow to have the weapon property [adaptive](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities/adaptive).

To add adaptive to the weapon, does it need to have an enhancement bonus like the weapon properties that use a bonus equivalent such as flaming?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, the bow can't have **adaptive** added without adding an enhancement bonus first. From the introduction to [Magic Weapon Special Abilities](http://www.d20pfsrd.com/magic-items/magic-weapons/magic-weapon-special-abilities):

> A weapon with a special ability must also have at least a +1 enhancement bonus.

Answer (score 6):

You must have a base enhancement bonus to add any magical special ability.

> A weapon with a special ability must also have at least a +1 enhancement bonus. - *Pathfinder RPG*, p. 468

In general, special abilities add directly to the effective enhancement bonus. However, there is no special exception for ones that add a linear/direct cost. They're are still special abilities and still require the underlying weapon to be enchanted.